# Need a nominalized synonym for the word "include"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

My dictionary lists the following verbs as synonyms for "include":

> 1. activities include sports and drama incorporate, comprise, encompass, cover, embrace, involve, take in, number, contain; consist of, be made up of, be composed of; formal comprehend. antonym exclude.
> 2. don't forget to include the cost of repairs allow for, count, take into account, take into consideration. antonym omit, leave out.

But I need a NOUN not a verb.

Comment: Um, look under *inclusion*?

Comment: I changed *noun* to *nominalized*, which means *converted to a noun*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three nominalized synonyms or *noun synonyms* that sprung to mind:

> *addition* • *addendum* • *extra*

The above examples, however, only work for the second definition of *include* in your quote, which means *to take into account*.

For the first sense of the word (*to incorporate, comprise*), you could try the following:

> *component • constituent • element • member • unit • item • ingredient • part • activity • type*, etc.

Comment: Thank you. That set me on the right path. "Addition" was the word I was trying to recall. "Extra" is another one that works. And I think I will go with "extras."

Comment: @Joshua: Indeed, I contemplated including *extra* initially, but now that you mention it, I will take the liberty to *include* it!!

Comment: +1 for figuring out what was being asked and answering it. I myself read the question and bowed out.

Comment: I'm doing translation work for a hotel and needed to get the wording right. I came up with "all extras included." I needed to use "included" and it would have been strange to say "all included stuff included." Great help Jimi.

Comment: quod includi debent includitur

Answer (score 4):

"Include" is a verb. Its corresponding/derived noun is "inclusion". A word with similar meaning is "incorporation"  [ *=To unite (one thing) with something else already in existence* ] (but it's not a synonym).